# Can't catch exceptions in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch, laravel-5.4, php-7.1

I have the following situation:

```
  try {

        DB::beginTransaction();

        $task = new Task();
        $task->setTracker("");
        //thrown \Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError


            DB::commit();

        }catch (\Exception $e){
            DB::rollBack();
            Log::error($e);
            //throw $e;
        }
```

I am not entering to the catch area.
Any idea why?

**update**

This is the error thrown:

`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]

Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Models\Task::setTracker() must be an instance of Carbon\Carbon, integer given, called in /var/www/app/Services/ShareLogic.php on line 60`

and will not be catched

Thanks

Comment: how do you know this line throws an error if you are not entering in catch area ?

Comment: @PankitGami see my update

Comment: Please add the code which you have write between `beginTransaction` and `commit`.

Comment: @PankitGami - done

Comment: Please share the answer with community.

Comment: See my edited answer. I think that might solve your problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Catching [`Throwable`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) did the trick.
Have no idea why?
Anyone does?

Comment: From the documentation: 

`Throwable is the base interface for any object that can be thrown via a throw statement in PHP 7, including Error and Exception.`

It would make sense that catching the base would catch it.

Answer (score 6):

It does not catch the exception because you are trying to catch `\Exception` which `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError` does not extend.

Instead try to catch the actual exception by importing it..

```
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError;
```

And then you can do..

```
try {
    // 
} catch(FatalThrowableError e) {
    // 
}
```

#### Edit

Ok, so in addition to the above solution it seems PHP 7+ handles error a bit differently than PHP 5. So try this..

```
try {
    // 
} catch(Error $e) {
    // This should work
} catch(Throwable $e) {
    // This should work as well
}
```

Comment: `FatalThrowableError` does inherit from `Exception` eventually. every exception needs to inherit from Exception. this is not JAVA, you can't expect every specific exception. this is not the case

Comment: SexyMF is correct. Following the inheritance chain back to the top yields `class FatalErrorException extends \ErrorException { ...`. Furthermore, straight form the PHP Manual: "Exception is the base class for all Exceptions in PHP 5, and the base class for all user exceptions in PHP 7." The OP's problem stems from another cause.

Comment: Alright, I provided another solution. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony's Debug component is much more sophisticated in order to log and report all kinds of errors but take look at this simple example (php 7.1.x):

```
<?php

class MyUncatchableError extends Exception {}

function myExceptionHandler($e) {
    throw new MyUncatchableError('BANG: '.$e->getMessage());
}

set_exception_handler('myExceptionHandler');

$foo = true;

try {
    $foo->modify();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'nope';
} catch (MyUncatchableError $e) {
    echo 'nope2';
}
```

What will be the outcome? Well:

> Fatal error: Uncaught MyUncatchableError: BANG: Call to a member function modify() on boolean in /in/WJErU:6
>
> Stack trace:
>
> - 0 [internal function]: myExceptionHandler(Object(Error))
> - 1 {main}
>
>   thrown in /in/WJErU on line 6

and you can't catch that exception because you should catch the original.. throwable here, which is [Error](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) for this kind of "error". You can catch it by catching "Error" class. And with PHP7 hierarchy it implements Throwable interface, that's why you can't catch it using Exception (because while Exception implements Throwable, Error is no an Exception - see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php).

And this is true for PHP7+ because with 5.* there was no Throwable nor Error, and doing `$foo->modify();` would just stop the script and return a Fatal Error. You can make your own error handler (`set_error_handler`) and throw an exception there (and Debug component does that for php 5.*) but this method does not work for Fatal Errors. Instead Debug component hooks into [script shutdown](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7974cd74e0410143e1ad8ace605b00869d5f88ca/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php#L116) and reads last error and [throws FatalErrorException](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7974cd74e0410143e1ad8ace605b00869d5f88ca/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php#L579).

This description may not be completely accurate as I have't dug deeply into Symfony but you can get the idea here.